# Can't access nested for loop in MPI Bcast

Tags: mpi, broadcast

I cannot access or print any data from the nested for loop. This is the first time I've ever wrote a MPI program and all the examples never show anything more complicated than a Hello World. What am I doing wrong?

```
void assignStarsToClusters(double *stars, double *clusters, int *azimuth)
{
ostringstream oss;

oss.str("");
oss.clear(); 

//double start = MPI_Wtime();   

// Assign a star to the closest cluster
double smallDistance;
double tmpDistance;
int indice = 0;

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Bcast(azimuth    /*the data we're broadcasting*/,
          NUMOFLINES /*the data size */,
          MPI_INT    /*the data type */,
          0          /*the process we're broadcasting from */,
          MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(stars    /*the data we're broadcasting*/,
          NUMOFSTARCOORD /*the data size */,
          MPI_DOUBLE    /*the data type */,
          0          /*the process we're broadcasting from */,
          MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(clusters    /*the data we're broadcasting*/,
          NUMOFCLUST /*the data size */,
          MPI_DOUBLE    /*the data type */,
          0          /*the process we're broadcasting from */,
          MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
MPI_Bcast(&NUMOFCLUST    /*the data we're broadcasting*/,
          1             /*the data size */,
          MPI_DOUBLE    /*the data type */,
          0          /*the process we're broadcasting from */,
          MPI_COMM_WORLD);     
MPI_Bcast(&NUMOFSTARCOORD    /*the data we're broadcasting*/,
          1             /*the data size */,
          MPI_DOUBLE    /*the data type */,
          0          /*the process we're broadcasting from */,
          MPI_COMM_WORLD);

int sx = NUMOFSTARCOORD/comm_sz;
int s_lower = my_rank * sx;
int s_upper = s_lower + sx;


for(int a = my_rank; a <= comm_sz; a++)
{ 
    for(int i = s_lower; i <= s_upper; i+=3)
    {
        smallDistance = sqrt(sqr(stars[i] - clusters[0]) + sqr(stars[i+1] - clusters[1]) + sqr(stars[i+2] - clusters[2]));

        indice = 0;

        for(int j = 3; j <= (NUMOFCLUST * 3); j+=3)
        {
            tmpDistance = sqrt(sqr(stars[i] - clusters[j]) + sqr(stars[i+1] - clusters[j+1]) + sqr(stars[i+2] - clusters[j+2]));

            oss << " " << j;        

            if(tmpDistance < smallDistance)
            {
                smallDistance = tmpDistance;
                indice = j;
            }           
        }
        azimuth[i/3] = indice / 3;  

        //oss << " " << indice;
    }
}
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   // cout << oss.str() << endl;   

//oss.str("");
//oss.clear();
//if(my_rank == 0)
//{
    //for (int i = 0; i < NUMOFLINES; i++) {
    //  oss << " " << azimuth[i];
    //}
//}


cout << oss.str() << endl;

//cout << "Total Time: " << MPI_Wtime() - start << endl;

 }
```

Comment: You can't expect that we teach to you MPI here on SO. Just search for "MPI tutorial" and start from there: there is plenty of examples further "hello world".

Comment: I've done a hello world and that doesn't help in this situation. Simple MPI programs don't help with the jump to real code. A little help to get me started would be nice. I understand the concepts, I just need some help with my first program.

Comment: It quite hard to tell you what's wrong without knowing how `azimuth`, `cluster`, `NUMOFSTARCOORD` are decleared. Here is a link to an example of `MPI_Bcast()` : http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Bcast.html

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you what I see wrong in your MPI code.

1. MPI_Barrier(): mostly never needed: `MPI_Bcast()` synchronizations are implicit - barriers are needed when you need to synchronize with something external, for example when ordering I/O to stdout.
2. this loop:

   ```
   for(int a = my_rank; a <= comm_sz; a++)
   ```

   It's not clear the intention. I hope that `my_rank` and `comm_sz` have been correctly initialized. Are you sure they are? are you correctly running your code with mpirun? But most importantly: I don't know why, but I have the feeling that you think that this loop is parallelized. The `a` loop-variable (what an horrible choice for its name) is not used in the loop. If my intuition is correct... well this isn't how MPI works.

   On the other side, if it is correct for your alogrithm (totally unclear), its unbalanced, because different MPI tasks will perform different number of iterations. So your code will perform as the slowest one, that is task with my_rank==0.
3. the reason for my negative comment is that you said "This is the first time I've ever wrote a MPI program" and you tried "hello world" only before. I strongly suggest that you try some more typical examples: distributed sums, ghost cells... Then when you have a better idea of how it works with simple test cases, you go on and get started with your own problem.
4. you should start posting here on SO a working code, extracted from your actual problem if too large to be practical. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): you will see that trying to explain it you will clarify yourself even before posting.
5. MPI_Bcast()'s - the title of the post - seem really correct: you should start printing them to start debugging the code, if you don't want to start with a parallel debugger (that wouldn't be a bad idea at all)... but it seems like you havent tried it either. I would start adding this line after the first MPI_Bcast():

   ```
   cout << my_rank << ": azimuth[0]="<< azimuth[0] << endl;
   ```

Hope it's more clear why of my criticism.